# Non-fatal Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException -- Android 10 11 12

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

I write this function to PDFfile form URI but it throw 2 exception with Android 10 11 12.

From Firebase Crashlytics

45% Xiaomi
14% samsung
12% oneplus
12% realme

38% Android 11
34% Android 12
19% Android 10
7% Android 9

1)

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.whatsapp.contentprovider.MediaProvider uri content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/b1003092-8514-4d91-8600-3bbdb788c2bf from pid=21402, uid=10231 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

2. 

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: myApp.scanner.docs.pdf has no access to content://media/external/downloads/65407
```

Funtion

```
   fun getPdfFileFromUri(activity: Context, pdfFileNames: Uri): File {
     val myFile: File
     var displayName: String? = null
     val uriString = pdfFileNames.toString()
     if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
 // following line responsible for crash 1
        cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(pdfFileNames, null, null, null, null)
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            displayName =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
        }
        cursor?.close()
        if (displayName == null) {
            displayName = uriString.split("/")[uriString.split("/").size - 1]
        }
        myFile = File(activity.cacheDir, displayName)
        val output = FileOutputStream(myFile)
 // following line responsible for 2nd crash
        val asset = activity.contentResolver.openInputStream(pdfFileNames)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var size: Int
        while (asset!!.read(buffer).also { size = it } != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, size)
        }
        asset.close()
        output.close()
    } else {
        myFile = File(uriString)
    }
    return myFile
}
```

Comment: Do you have define of file provider in manifest? 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: Can you first tell what that function should do? Can you then tell the value of the pdfFileNames parameter with which you call that function? We wanna see how many and which names you put in it.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I make this function in utills and used  it with 3 different activity.
I'm facing issue when i open pdf file from fileManger via intent. also i want to inform that this issue doesn't happen every time.

Comment: @blackapps function fetch pdf file from local using URI. & function use single URI at a time.

Comment: So much code for fetching or reading a file? For that you only have to open an input stream and read from it. Three lines. Why do you have so much more code? And why didnt you put the used uri string in your code so we know what you do?  Also explain what 'fetching' a file would be. Realise that the file is already on your device otherwise there was no uri.